# Time.valueOf method returning wrong value

Tags: java, time, localtime

I used the method Time.valueOf to convert the String "09:00:00" into Time object as follows: Time.valueOf (LocalTime.parse("09:00:00")).

When I call getTime () to display the value I get: 28800000 ms instead of 32400000‬‬ ms (calculated from calculator).

Did I make an error when I used Time.value Of ? Because I don't understand why I get the wrong value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Stick to java.time.LocalTime

I recommend you stick to `LocalTime` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, and don’t use `java.sql.Time`. The latter class is poorly designed, a true hack, indeed, on top of the already poorly designed `java.util.Date` class. Fortunately it’s also long outdated. There was a time when we needed a `Time` object for storing a time of day into a database column of datatype `time` or transferring a time to an SQL query using that datatype. Since JDBC 4.2 this is no longer the case. Now your JDBC driver accepts a `LocalTime` object and passes its time value on to the database.

So if you’ve got a string, parse it into a `LocalTime` object the way you already did:

```
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("09:00:00");
```

If you don’t need to go through a string, you may obtain the same result using the `of` factory method, for example:

```
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(9, 0);
```

I don’t know why you should want to convert it to milliseconds, but you can:

```
    int milliOfDay = time.get(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_DAY);
    System.out.println(milliOfDay);
```

Output is:

> 32400000

This is the value you said you expected.

To insert the `LocalTime` into your database:

```
    PreparedStatement ps = yourDatabaseConnection.prepareStatement(
            "insert into your_table(your_time_col) values (?)");
    ps.setObject(1, time);
    int rowsInserted = ps.executeUpdate();
```

Note the use of `setObject()`, not `setTime()`.

If you do need a `Time` object for some legacy API that you don’t want to upgrade just now, the conversion you made is correct.

### Your expectations were wrong, your conversion was correct

> Did I make an error when I used Time.value Of ? Because I don't
>   understand why I get the wrong value.

No, the other way around. You made no error. And in this case you got the correct value. It’s the poor and confusing design of `Time` playing a trick on you (I said you shouldn’t want to use that class). I am not sure it’s documented, but `Time.valueOf (LocalTime.parse("09:00:00"))` gives you a `Time` object that internally holds a point in time of Jan 1, 1970 09:00 *in the time zone of your JVM*. From the millisecond value you got, 28 800 000, it seems that this time is equal to 08:00 UTC. Was your time zone at UTC offset +01:00 in the winter of 1970? The `getTime()` method returns the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 00:00 *UTC*.

Answer (score 3):

That's caused by time zone issues. If you do

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Before your code you will get 32400000‬‬ as you expect.

`Time.valueOf (LocalTime.parse("09:00:00"))` assumes the nine is at your local time zone so it converts it to UTC.

For example if the time zone is `"Asia/Jerusalem"` (you can simulate it with `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Jerusalem"));` which was UTC+2 at 1 January 1970 it will convert 9 o'clock to 7 o'clock. You can see it with `System.out.println(time.toGMTString());`

As always in questions about the old java time api I have to give you an obligatory recommendation to always use only the [modern](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) post java8 api.

Comment: For my own understanding: `java.sql.time` is a thin wrapper around `java.util.date` (it says [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html#valueOf(java.lang.String))). And `date` uses the local TZ... Is that the source of this issue?

Comment: @andrewjames I added an explanation.