# Error in a coversion from Time to Long (Milliseconds)

Tags: java

I'm new on Java and the convertion formats and I have a doubt with my convertion, this the code

```
Time time_normal_format;
long time_milliseconds;

time_milliseconds = time_normal_format.getTime();
//time_normal_format prints on screen "00:00:05"//

System.out.println("Time in milliseconds: "+time_milliseconds);
```

My doubt it's why my convertion sets "21605000" on time_milliseconds instead only 5000.

Comment: 21600000 would represent 6 hours - any chance you are 6 hours from UTC?  Printing usually involves time zone adjustments whereas the raw time value may be referenced to UTC or some other common time reference.  Which time class package are you referring to?

Comment: Are you trying to get a count of milliseconds between midnight and a time-of-day value?

Comment: Is 00:00:05 a time of day (5 seconds past midnight) or is it an amount of time, for example a duration? Asking because those two are handled very differently in Java.

Comment: Under all circumstances I recommend you don’t use `java.sql.Time`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalTime` for a time of day or `Duration` for an amount of time; both are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Related: [Time.valueOf method returning wrong value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61448647/time-valueof-method-returning-wrong-value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## tl;dr

```java
Duration
.between(
    LocalTime.MIDNIGHT , 
    myJavaSqlTime.toLocalTime()
)
.toMillis()
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Apparently you are using [`java.sql.Time`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Time.html) class. **Don’t.**

The date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java are *terrible*, written by people who did not understand the nuances and complexities of date-time handling. Add on some very poor choices in design, and the result is an awful mess.

## *java.time*

The legacy date-time classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes.

### `LocalTime`

To represent a time-of-day, without a date and without a time zone, use [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html).

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 15 , 30 ) ;    // 3:30 PM
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "15:30" ) ; // ditto
```

To get a count of milliseconds since midnight, use `Duration`.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( LocalTime.MIDNIGHT , lt ) ;
long millis = d.toMillis() ;
```

Going the other direction, from a count of milliseconds since midnight to a time-of-day.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofMillis( 5_000 ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.MIDNIGHT.plus( d ) ;
```

Keep in mind that this kind of code only works for generic 24-hour days. In the real world, in various time zones, days can be other than 24 hours long. They can be 23 or 25 hours with Daylight Saving Time (DST) cutovers. And they can actually be any length as dictated by politicians, such as 23.5 hours, or off by 15 minutes, or any other adjustment deemed worthwhile for various political, cultural, diplomatic, or martial reasons.

#### Conversion to/from legacy class

If you must interoperate with some old code not yet updated to *java.time*, you can easily convert back-and-forth. Look to new methods added to the old classes. If given a `java.sql.Time` object, call [`toLocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Time.html#toLocalTime()) to get a `LocalTime` object.

```
LocalTime lt = myJavaSqlTime.toLocalTime() ;
```

Going the other direction, from modern class to legacy class.

```
java.sql.Time myJavaSqlTime = Time.valueOf( lt ) ;
```

### `Duration`

If your real goal is to represent a span-of-time not related to the clock or calendar, then you should *not* be using `LocalTime` or `java.sql.Time`.

You should instead be using [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) class to represent a span of time on the scale of hours-minutes-seconds while unattached to the timeline. (For a scale of years-month-days, use `Period` class.)

To represent such a span-of-time textually, I strongly recommend *not* using clock-time formatting such as `00:00:05`. Such strings are inherently ambiguous, looking like a time-of-day.

#### ISO 8601

Instead, use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format: `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`. The `P` marks the beginning. The `T` separates any years-months-days from any hours-minutes-seconds. So your example of five seconds would be `PT5S`.

The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating date-time text.

```
Duration d = Duration.parse( "PT5S" ) ;
```

Going the other direction.

```
String output = Duration.ofSeconds( 5 ).toString() ;   // PT5S
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).